# Use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 with a light theme

Tags: android, listview, themes

I have learned that when using `android:entries` with a `ListView`, it uses `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as the layout for a list item and `android.R.id.text1` as the ID of the TextView inside that layout. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Knowing this, I wanted to create my own adapter but use the same layout resources, in order to provide UI consistency with the platform. Thus, I tried the following:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    getApplicationContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    mSites,
    new String[] { SitesDatabase.KEY_SITE },
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }
);
```

Unfortunately, because I am using a light theme (I have `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"` in my `<application>`), the list items appear with white text, making them unreadable.

However, when using `android:entries` to specify a static list of items, the items appear correctly, with black text color.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make my dynamic adapter use the standard layout but work with a light theme?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

You are at least sorta wrong. It uses `com.android.internal.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. While that is nearly identical to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, it may be themed differently.

Also, never use `getApplicationContext()`. Just use your `Activity` as the `Context`. See if that helps.

Comment: Indeed, using `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` fixes it. Wow! Thanks!

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, `getApplicationContext()` is a seriously messed-up method. It gives you an `Application` object, which is a `Context`, but apparently doesn't do well with any GUI-related stuff related to `Context`s. Unless you actually need the `Application` object (e.g., you have a custom one), I would never use `getApplicationContext()`. After all, that method is a method...on `Context`. So, by definition, you already have a perfectly delightful `Context`. I'm glad this worked!

Comment: I was always under the impression that `getApplicationContext()` was somehow more *correct* (what if they change how contexts work and `this` is no longer a `Context`? `getApplicationContext()` would probably be updated to reflect the changes in the API and I wouldn't have to refactor my code). Thanks for clearing that up :)