# Android ListView Text Color

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to set the ListView textColor to black, since I am using a white background.

Here is my MailActivity

```
public class MailActivity extends ListActivity {

    String[] listItems = { "Compose", "Inbox", "Drafts", "Sent" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mails);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));

    }
}
```

and my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/empty" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Empty set" 
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting the background as white, but am not sure where to set the foreground to black. I've tried in the xml and looks like it's not helping.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Ok, here are some things that you should be clear about:

1. The background color you are setting in your xml file is of the activity and not of the ListItems you are trying to define.
2. Every list item has its own layout file which should be passed or inflated in case you are using complex layout for list item.

I'll try to explain this with a code sample:

****Lets start with ListItems layout** **: save it in your `res/layout` folder of you Android project with say **list_black_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Definig a container for you List Item-->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Defining where should text be placed. You set you text color here-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sample"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Well, a simple layout with a `TextView` to be precise. You must have an id assigned to TextView in order to use it.

Now coming to you screen/activity/chief layout, as I said you are defining background to your screen with `android:background` attribute. I see you have defined a TextView there as well and I suspect you are trying to define content/list item there, which is not at all needed.

Here's your edited layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <!-- REMOVED TEXT VIEW, AND KEEPING BACKGROUND WHITE -->
</LinearLayout>
```

And lastly, most importantly, set your adapter.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.list_black_text, R.id.list_content, listItems));
```

Notice the layout resource which we are passing to adapter `R.layout.list_black_text`, and `R.id.list_content` which is TextView ID we declared. I have also changed ArrayAdapter to String type since it's generic.

I hope this explains everything. Mark my answer accepted if you agree.

**Messy but a good quick fix way**
You can also do this with a quick fix if you do not want to go ahead with complex layout defining etc.

While instantiating the adapter declare an inner class to do this, here is the code sample:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            /*YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR*/
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            return view;
        }
    };

    /*SET THE ADAPTER TO LISTVIEW*/
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. i never knew there was a seperate xml file for ListView

Comment: This gives me the error: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView. How did you manage to get this to work without writing your own adapter?

Comment: @odiggity, use 4 argument constructor rather than a 3. if you are already doing that then the 3rd arg in 4 arg constructor is an id reference to the textview described in your list item layout, in short R.id.list_content in my example is id referring to textview in my list item layout specified with R.layout.list_black_text

Comment: Nice, but a short and [straight solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8921087/593709).

Comment: Way too long for defining one color don't you think?

Comment: It gives me an error that  getView is undefined for ListActivity. I wish to extend ListActivity instead of Activity.

Answer (score 23):

1. Create a styles file, for example: `my_styles.xml` and save it in `res/values`.
2. Add the following code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>

   <style name="ListFont" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
       <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
       <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
   </style>

   </resources>
   ```
3. Add your style to your `Activity` definition in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as an `android:theme` attribute, and assign as value the name of the style you created. For example:

   ```
   <activity android:name="your.activityClass" android:theme="@style/ListFont">
   ```

---

NOTE: the `Widget.ListView` comes from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html.). Also check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.).

Comment: I tried this and it's changing the title bar's color, not the list item's color.

Comment: its great, i like it... because i am dynamically adding items in listview. I did not required to define any textview....

Comment: do you set whole ListView style to activity?

Answer (score 16):

I cloned the `simple_list_item_1`(Alt + Click) and placed the copy on my `res/layout` folder, renamed it to `list_white_text.xml` with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

The `android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"` translates to white on my device.

then in the `java` code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_white_text, myList);
```

Comment: this is the simplest and cleanest solution!

Comment: The Best Solution!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the text color in the layout *simple_list_item_1* that defines the layout of each of your items.

You set the background color of the LinearLayout and not of the ListView. The background color of the child items of the LinearLayout are transparent by default (in most cases).

And you set the black text color for the TextView that is not part of your ListView. It is an own item (child item of the LinearLayout) here.

Answer (score 1):

never use `getApplicationContext()`. Just use your Activity as the Context. See if that helps.

Please check here:
[CommonsWare answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001483/use-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1-with-a-light-theme)

Comment: Actually, this is the best solution. If anyone else is having same problem then just try out this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your code:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

for (int i = 0; i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
    ((TextView)lv.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
}
```

Comment: Up-voting from -1, as this works fine, if you do the correct type-cast of lv.getChildAt(i), e.g. in my case the typecast was to AppCompatCheckedTextView

Comment: not working solution

Answer (score 0):

if you didnot set your activity style it shows you black background .if you want to make changes such as white background, black text of listview then it is difficult process.

**ADD**  **android:theme="@style/AppTheme"** **in Android Manifest**.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make a `ListView` with items of different colors. I modified Shardul's method a bit and result in this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, colorString) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(assignBackgroundColor(position));
                textView.setTextColor(assignTextColor(position));
                return textView;
            }
        };
        colorList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`assignBackgroundColor()` and `assignTextColor()` are methods that assign color you want. They can be replaced with `int[]` arrays.