# How to set the text at center in ListView android application?

Tags: android, listview, text, get, center

I have implemented an application on ListView in my application i have used getListView() method.I have written code as follows:

```
   String[] conversionsadd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.conversions);
   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,conversionsadd));
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listback2);
```

when i write the above code at onCreate method i can able to show the list with some texts.
from the above code i would like to display the text in center in the list and also display the text in a color.

Comment: Just use `android:layoutGravity="center"` to your listview. But, in here you're using android default's listview. Try to use your own listview instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you are using built-in layout which is

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

this layout cannot be changed. However you can provide your own row layout.

your row should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" 
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

remember that the id should be only `android:id="@android:id/text1"`

and now you can give this to your ArrayAdapter's constructor:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.my_custom_layout,conversionsadd);
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly, just one thing I found was that in Android Studio, the 'Design' will not show these changes - but they can be seen when you use the emulator.

Answer (score 6):

I didnot try, but I think, overriding getView in adapter method, and do the following:

```
String[] conversionsadd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.conversions);
   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,conversionsadd)
{
    public View getView(AdapterView adapterView, View convertView, int position, long id)
    {

         View view=super.getView(adapterView, convertView, position, id);
         TextView txt=view.findViewById(android.R.id.textView1);
         txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

         return view;
    }
});
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listback2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should give the code of the `getView` function of `ArrayAdapter` or XML of `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, which is normally where the style of the listview item is set