# Android: ListView xml layout not showing background image when scrolled

Tags: android, listview, scroll, background-image, listitem

I have an Activity with a ListView, I set the background image to the view programatically.
When I scroll down my list, the background image turns to white ( because my theme is Theme.Light.NoTitleBar).

1. How can I make it scroll with the blue background intact?
2. If the above point works, how can I change the text color of ListView to white instead of black?

Normal ListView
[image: Normal ListView]

Scrolling ListView
[image: Scrolling ListView]

Pressing ListView item
[image: Pressing ListView item]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the attribute `android:cacheColorHint="#000000"` in `ListView` Tag
2. Regarding make `TextView's` color black or white, you can [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8921087/593709) to make a custom `TextView` for your `ListView` row, The extra work you have to do is just add another attribut inside `TextView` tag like this

   `android:textColor="#FFF" //or #FFFFFF for white`

Comment: the only answer that got back to both my questions, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

add a attribute on the ListView Tag

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"// setting as a transparent color
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due because of an optimization. To remove this, just set the cacheColorHint of your listView to transparent, like this: `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`

Full post here: http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap that **ListView** inside on **LinearLayout** having same background and then remove **ListView**'s **Background** that should work fine. :)

Comment: this is workaround not a solution and i don't think so i should be down Voted for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31175719/1071545) answer.   I have got the same issue and it is fixed by putting view = null in adapter side.