# listView Centered in a dialog in Android

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I am trying to have the content of the ListView centered when displayed in a dialog.
This is my code to show the ListView

```
String[] myItems = {"item1", "item2", "item3"}; 

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,  R.layout.setting_layout, myItems);

ListView list = (ListView) deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setFadingEdgeLength(5);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paret, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
 }
```

And this is the xml part:

```
 TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp"
```

and this is the layout of delete dialog:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

</ListView>
```

Its running but the content is always displayed to left.
I tried this: [How to set the text at center in ListView android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921037/how-to-set-the-text-at-center-in-listview-android-application)
but it didn't work.

Hope anyone can guide me through.

Comment: What happens if you set `android:gravity="center"` to ListView?

Comment: In fact I haven't tried it. The thing is when I write android: it starts giving the options that I could use, and gravity was not among them so I just assumed that I couldn't use. I just tried it, it didn't give an error, but still its giving items to the left

Comment: change ur linearlayout's width to fill_parent instead of wrap_content

Comment: welcome i have written it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work for u

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your LinearLayout to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
```

Comment: still giving the same result

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

I hope it helps