# duplicate attributes android xml

Tags: android, xml

Apparently I have duplicate attributes but cannot spot this,  I have gone through the XML line by line but cannot see what's wrong.  I have tried to clean, build and have also closed eclipse and opened it again.  Also this is a new xml file I created in layout as I wanted to change the text displayed within listview instead of using the standard one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp" 
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
```

Here is a screenshot of where the error is pointing to
[SCREENSHOT](http://gyazo.com/54ee215df7f63b36182ffd8d92f87e91)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error on eclipse please?

Comment: could You please Show us the complete layout?

Comment: have You cleaned the Project after changing to what invisbo said?

Comment: and, please Show the complete XML...or is this really all?

Comment: yeahh thats all of it.  I created the xml using the options in eclipse.  Also yes I cleaned the project after I made changes according to invisbo's suggestion.

Comment: I tried to follow the answer given to this question, but not sure if I have done it correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921037/how-to-set-the-text-at-center-in-listview-android-application

Comment: ok, it is just an assumption, but the id "text1" is used by android System listview to refer to the internal build textview. What happens if You just use another id like @+id=my_text_view_1 ?

Comment: great...I put it as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it is just an assumption, but the id "text1" is used by android System listview to refer to the internal build textview. Just use another id like

```
   android:id="@+id/my_textview_1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess problem is this line: `android:id="@android:id/text1"`

change it with this `android:id="@+id/text1"`

Comment: I have changed as accordingly but I still get the same error