# “ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView” issue

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, layout

I seem to have problems using custom styles for ListView.

All online searches (stackOverflow and other sites) pty much say the same: - create an my_style.xml layout file. - use it in the adapter.

But for some reason this doesn't seem to be working for me. 
MainAct.java:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.list_content, items);
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#0000DD"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

saved as /res/layout/list_content.xml.

If I use the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 everything works fine, with the own xml file I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView".

Any ideas?

PS: I already looked at lots of other very similar questions/issues, including:

["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/)

[How to set the text at center in ListView android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921037/)

[Android ListView Text Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView` clearly says. You need to pass the textview on which you need to show the data. Also, when you are using your own layout then `R.java` should belong to your project not `android.R`.

Change

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.list_content, items);
```

to

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_content, R.id.textview, items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is because of you are passing wrong type of argument.

After seeing your code I can say you want to use following version of ArrayAdapter.

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

So following will work for you according to the code snippet provided by you.

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_content, R.id.textview, items);
```

for different versions of arrayAdapter you can refer to :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is declaring xml in your package and trying to access it from `android.R.layout` package.
So, change

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.list_content, items);
```

to

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_content, items);
```

It'll work

Comment: I have the second and still don't work... if my list.xml file contains 2 textview do I need to pass all of them to my arrayAdapter? thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't return the `super.getView(...)`-Method in `getView()`

```
   override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
     return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
   }
```

instead, return your inflated view

```
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val view: View

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resourceId, parent, false)
    } else {
        view = convertView
    }

        return view
    }
```