# Issue with XML display font (Android)

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to display my parsed JSON in a ListView, but there is a little problem with the text in the ListView always appearing as a light grey, even though I have specified the font color as #000000

Code snippet that calls the list:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));           
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: check your list view items text color. I think you may be over-riding this value.

Comment: Before opening a new thread use search function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about that.