# How to change hashmap items color

Tags: android, colors, hashmap

I want to change the color just first and second item in the hashmap.
I know  i can use  getView but  is there any solution for hashmaps?
I have two string arrays which are array1 and array 2.

```
ListView listview1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (int i=0; i<array2.length; i++) {
            Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            datum.put("title",array1[i]);
            datum.put("subtitle", String.valueOf(array2[i]));
            data.add(datum);


        }
        SimpleAdapter adapter3 = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,
                                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                                              new String[] {"title", "subtitle"},
                                              new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                                                         android.R.id.text2});
       listview1.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gta6"

    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What??? HashMap? I think you have wrong concept about HashMap. You can  not do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change font type and color in this listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801286/how-to-change-font-type-and-color-in-this-listview)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your `HashMap` value type to `CharSequence` and use `Spannable`...

```
    List<Map<String, CharSequence>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, CharSequence>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        Map<String, CharSequence> datum = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>(2);
        String s1 = array1[i];
        String s2 = String.valueOf(array2[i]);
        if(i == 0 || i == 1) {
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(s1);
            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            datum.put("title", spannableString);
            spannableString = new SpannableString(s2);
            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            datum.put("subtitle", spannableString);
        } else {
            datum.put("title", s1);
            datum.put("subtitle", s2);
        }
        data.add(datum);
    }
```

Comment: it works but it does not affect the color.I dont understand why?

Comment: Why it is downvoted? the person who downvoted it, should give the proper reason for downvoting...