# Add formatted text to a ListView

Tags: java, android

I am looking to add formatted text to a `ListView` (I would like the text to be the color #33B5E5). This is what I tried so far:

```
ArrayList myarraylist;
String mystring = "Value I want to add"
myarraylist.add(mystring);
//other functions to set the arraylist
```

My question is, how would I change the color of `mystring`? Is it possible to set the text color of a string?

Comment: Do it in customized list adapter

Comment: check the answer in this its pretty much the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color

Comment: @JRowan Read the question carefully I'm trying to make only some text in the ListView formatted, your link is about making the whole ListView formatted. Read before you comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ArrayAdapter, and create a `List<SpannableString>`, `SpannableString` is implementation of `CharSequence`, so it can behaviors like `CharSequence`.

the code below is to create a MAGENTA color text.

```
msp = new SpannableString("Hello I am colo Magenta"); 
msp.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.MAGENTA), 12, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
myTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.orange.black));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add fontcolor to your string...

```
ArrayList<String> myarraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        String mystring = "<font color='#33B5E5'>Value I want to add</font>";
        myarraylist.add(mystring);
```

add it to textview...

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTime)).setText(Html.fromHtml(myarraylist.get(0)), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```