# Android XML: Text Color does not change?

Tags: android, xml, colors, textview

however my text color will not change it's color to black.

I don't know what the problem could be... do you have any idea?

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:color="#000000" >
```

EDIT:

My manifest is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.blabla.blabla"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

     >
    <activity
        android:name=".blablabla"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my styles.xml is empty

```
<resources>



</resources>
```

EDIT:

i think i solved my problem..

the solution: [Android ListView Text Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color)

i aded a style:

```
<style name="ListFont" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView"> <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item> <item name="android:typeface">sans</item> </style>
```

and added it in my manifest...

in my activity i used this:

`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.BlaBla, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);`

i ask myself what exactly  "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 does? - why my textColor did not worked and why it does work now with a seperate style -  do i need to mention simple_list_item_1 then in my activity any more?

thx u guys

Comment: Did you set a custom theme for your TextView in your styles.xml?

Comment: Try changing android:id="@android:id/empty" to android:id="@+id/empty"

Comment: why do you expect a different color ?

Comment: @Steve `#000000` is black.

Comment: @JJ86 no, my styles.xml is full empty.

Comment: the current color shown is something like white -> grey

but i want black - but somehow it does not do it...

Comment: i think its because of that layout, that uses font color white??: simple_list_item_1

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.BlaBla, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

but does  the textcolor not have to get changed when i set textcolor in my xml? but it does not^^

Comment: yeah, i did it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color

- created a style, put it in manifest...

Comment: but what exactly does "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 do?
- why my textColor did not worked and why it does work now with a seperate style - <style name="ListFont" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>

do i need to mention simple_list_item_1 then in my activity? when i use the style?