# Need to apply a color to my ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors, android-arrayadapter

In android I want to apply a color to my ListView.

Here is the `ListView`:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView1)
```

and my adapter to display the list:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
ArrayofName);
listView.setAdapter (adapter);
```

My variable that contains the color: `int textColor`. How I could do it? For example you can change the background of the list like this:

```
listView.setBackgroundColor(textColor);
```

But I want to change the color of text.

Comment: This link may help [Apply Color to Listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this

```
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allData) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FBB117"));

        return view;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is ViewGroup and why when I put it to my code it is turned red? Thanks))

Comment: Thanks a lot))))))))))))))))) It works)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It makes me  feel happy!!!))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

you are using:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

create a new XML file your_custom_layout.xml with a textview with ID mytextview1 and set the color of text in the XML as

```
android:textColor="#ff0000"
```

and then set your adapter like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.your_custom_layout, R.id.mytextview1, ArrayofName));
```

Comment: In fact, the user can choose the color he wants in a dialogBox with ColorPicker and when he clicked ok, this color goes to the the textColor variable which I want to apply to my listview. That's why I think I can not use an xml(

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use custom TextView xml for changing text color in ListView item.

Another simplest way is to create a layout file containing the textview you want with textSize, textStyle, color etc preferred by you and then use it with the ArrayAdapter.

**list_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:textColor="@color/mycolor"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Change your code to use this textview instead of simple_list_item_1 like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.list_text,
ArrayofName);
listView.setAdapter (adapter);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that the user himself can choose any color he wants and this color is contained in the textColor variablve. I just need to apply this color to the listview.

Comment: Then you will have to make custom adapter for your listview. Refer Sonu Raj's answer

Comment: Thanks a lot))))))))))))))))) It works)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It makes me  feel happy!!!))))))))))))))))