# How to setup Toolbar in Activity which doesn't extends AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have created an activity which extends ListActivity I want to setup Toolbar into my activity which requires to extends AppCompatActivity. Is there any way like fragments which imports AppCompatActivity like this

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ListView in your onCreate inside your AppCompatActivity. You cannot use the Toolbar with ListActivity.

In your onCreate

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view); 

mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please tell me how can I change the Text color in ListFragment or ListActivity ?

Comment: The easiest way is to set it up in the XML. I believe you can use a TextView element: android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark". More info please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color

Answer (score 2):

ListeActivity extends Activity, so you can't cast to AppCompatActivity.

Two alternatives would be to use ListFragment instead and put that into an AppCompatActivity. Or define your own ListAppCompatActivity class that includes a layout with a ListView with the id `android:id/list`

Answer (score 0):

`ListActivity` has a default `ListView` in it which can be referenced by `getListView()` method.

You can only have a `ToolBar` in Android by extending `AppCompatActivity`. `ActionBarActivity` has a `ActionBar` which is deprecated in since version 22.1.0.

So I insist you to go with `AppCompatActivity` for setting `ToolBar` amd inside that Activity you can have a `listview`.