# How to set color of text in my ListView

Tags: android, listview

Here I hace set color of row for value in ListView. Now i want set only color this string, no all row

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, DevicesList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "clients", "stan"},
                    new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.clients, enabled}){
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.enabled);
                    String a = v.getText().toString();

                    if (a == "Aktywny") {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125,53,104,45));
                    } else if(a == "Nieaktywny") {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125,175,43,30));
                    } else{
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125,139,140,122));
                    }

                    return view;
                }
            };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView Text Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533440/android-listview-text-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v.setTextColor(Color.argb(125,175,43,30))
```