# ListView Greyed Out

Tags: android, listview, textview, fragment

So I've run into a pretty peculiar issue here. I am using a navigation drawer that has the framelayout to switch out content. I current have two fragments built, one is just fine and the only thing it has in it is a button, no layout specified. My second fragment though has a relative layout with a textview and a listview.

When I load the listview (which uses the textview) I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the listview is greyed out. I have no immediate colors set in my layout for this so it's not all grey text, and I can still click each item and scroll the list. I have no idea what is causing this, any tips?

**EDIT** Here are snippets of my code where I am working with the layout:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read_it, container,
            false);
```

And here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/info"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
      android:id="@+id/listView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

And lastly my adapt and list:

```
ArrayAdapter<PressRelease> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PressRelease>(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pressReleases);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you show us the layout and the way you are adding it please.

Comment: **UPDATE** If I give my listview a dark color, it's fine and the text turns white, but without that my listview looks the same: white with greyed out looking text.

Answer (score 0):

Please give specific color to textview like

```
<TextView
android:width="match_parent"
android:height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
>
```

And in list view put cache color hint as transparent like

```
<ListView
android:width="match_parent"
android:height="wrap_content"
android:cacheColorHint="@andorid:color/transparent"
>
```

Comment: If I use the cacheColorHint, and actually add a color it will turn that color as I scroll, but it's still the same otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in another thread.
[Use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 with a light theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001483/use-android-r-layout-simple-list-item-1-with-a-light-theme)

I was using getApplicationContext() with my adapter, and for some reason using this with the light theme makes the colors on the listview light.